# Proving that if $\frac{x+y}{3} = \frac{y+z}{8} = \frac{z+x}{6}$, then $\frac{x+y+z}{2x+3y+3z} = \frac{17}{50}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

There's a problem as follows:

> If
> $$\frac{x+y}{3} = \frac{y+z}{8} = \frac{z+x}{6}$$
> prove that
> $$\frac{x+y+z}{2x+3y+3z} = \frac{17}{50}$$

I started solved it as follows:

#first : I added antecedents and consequents :
\begin{aligned}
\frac{(x+y+y+z+z+x)}{3+8+6} = \frac{2x +2y+2z}{17} 
\end{aligned}

#Then I multiplied both terms of second ratio by 2 , then I added all antecedents and consequents
\begin{aligned}
\frac{x+y+2y+2z+z+x}{3+16+6} = \frac{2x+3y+3z}{25} 
\end{aligned}

I stopped at here and couldn't know what's the next steps should I do?
Are these steps correct?

Comment: You have already solved the problem! The two results you found are equal

Comment: @coffeemath equal ratios can be added by adding numerators and denominators.

Comment: Alternative approach: express both $~y~$ and $~z~$ in terms of $~x.$

Comment: I deleted my comment since it is ok to add tops and bottoms for equal ratios.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\frac{x+y}{3} = \frac{y+z}{8} = \frac{z+x}{6}=:k$ (Where, $k\ne 0$)

$\therefore x+y=3k\ldots(1)\\\,y+z=8k\ldots(2)\\\,z+x=6k\ldots(3)$

$(1)-(2)+(3)$,

$x+y-(y+z)+z+x=3k-8k+6k\\\Rightarrow 2x=k\\\Rightarrow x=\frac{k}2$

Substituting, $x=\frac{k}2$ in both $(1)$ and $(3)$ equations,

We get, $y=\frac{5k}{2}; \, z=\frac{11k}{2}$

LHS$=\frac{x+y+z}{2x+3y+3z} =\frac{\frac{k}{2}+\frac{5k}{2}+\frac{11k}{2}}{\frac{2k}{2}+\frac{15k}{2}+\frac{33k}{2}}=\frac{17k}{50k}=\frac{17}{50}$=RHS$\square$

Answer (score 2):

You are using the result that, if a set of ratios is equal: $\frac{a}{b} = \frac{c}{d} = \frac{e}{f} = ... = r$, say, then also $$\frac{\alpha a+\beta c + \gamma e + ...}{\alpha b+\beta d + \gamma f + ...} =r.$$ Therefore both the expressions you have found are equal to the common ratio of $\frac{x+y}{3}$, $\frac{y+z}{8}$ and $\frac{z+x}{6}$, and so equal to each other.

Answer (score 2):

Your argument is/ should be basically this:

$$ \frac{x+y}{3} = \frac{x+y+y+z+z+x}{3+8+6} = \frac{2x +2y+2z}{17} $$

and

$$ \frac{x+y}{3} = \frac{2x+2y+4y+4z+2z+2x}{6+32+12} = \frac{4x +6y+6z}{50} $$

Therefore,

$$ \frac{2x +2y+2z}{17} = \frac{4x +6y+6z}{50} $$

$$ \implies \frac{2x +2y+2z}{4x +6y+6z} = \frac{17}{50}. $$

Comment: Exactly, this is how I presume the problem should have been done in the first place.